# Can I know if a nested __get is being requested?

Tags: php, overriding

I have a custom class called `NestedObject` which acts like `ArrayObject`, within which I am using recursion through arrays to created nested instances of the class; So if I pass it an array, any nested arrays become an instance of `NestedObject`.

I'm using `__get` to allow me to do similar to `$obj->my->path->through->arrays`.

I would like to know if there is any way within a `__get` call to know if there are any more `__get` calls lined up? What I mean is, can a call on `through` know that `arrays` is being called?

Comment: No, you can't detect that. But if all subarrays become `NestedObject`s anyway, why would you need to?

Comment: Your __get returns `NestedObject`, isn't it? You can't to know what fields will accessed on it.

Comment: @mario I'm trying to ascertain the last call, so I can convert it back to an array.